# Elixir's use with function name

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Recently I've stumbled upon this code

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.PageLive do
  use MyAppWeb, :live_view
```

It's part of default app generated with Phoenix Live View (`mix phx.new --live`).
It's first time when I see the `use` construct with a function name as a second argument.
I've tried to search the web on some docs about it but couldn't find a proper naming for this.

Can you help me understand what happens when this executes?

It doesn't call `__using__` macro but calls a function instead, and I'm not sure whether I can pass some options there, or I need to use the "normal" way (with `__using__` macro).
I've tried something like `use MyAppWeb, :live_view, opts` but that raises `undefined function use/3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__using__/1` is *just a macro*, and `use Mod, args` is just syntactic sugar for `Mod.__using__(args)`.

> It doesn't call `__using__/1` macro but calls a function instead [...]

Plain wrong, it calls `MyAppWeb.__using__/1` macro.

If you’d open your (also generated) `MyAppWeb`, you’ll find there somewhat like

```rb
  defmacro __using__(which) when is_atom(which) do
    apply(__MODULE__, which, [])
  end
```

That said, you might call `which` directly, or amend `MyAppWeb.__using__/1` to accept arguments.

Comment: Actually `MyAppWeb` looks like this: `defmodule MyAppWeb do
  ...
  def live_view do
    quote do
      ...
    end
  end
  ...
end`

Comment: Oh damn... I didn't scroll to the end <facepalm>

Comment: If `__using__/1` is not defined in `Mod`, `use Mod` would not compile :)

Comment: Also, consider reading https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html closely. The use macro is conceptually grouped with require, import and alias, and this page gives a great explanation of each.